# UIButton didn't call to target method

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have the following code:

```
UIImage *registerImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"register_button_normal"];
CGFloat registerOffsetX = (view.frame.size.width - registerImg.size.width) / 2;

UIButton *registerBtnTwo = [[UIButton alloc] init];
registerBtnTwo.frame = CGRectMake(registerOffsetX, 111, registerImg.size.width, registerImg.size.height);

[registerBtnTwo setBackgroundImage:registerImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[registerBtnTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(submitRegister) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[registerPanel addSubview:registerBtnTwo];
[registerBtnTwo release];
```

I have `- (void)submitRegister;` in class headers as instance method;

The problem is event isn't fired because i have NSLog in my submitRegister implementation

What i've tried:

```
1. UIButton *registerBtnTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

2. UIButton *registerBtnTwo = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

EDIT 1: Who i add the current View Controller to my navigationController ?

```
if ( row == kLoginRegisterIndex ) {
    login = [[LoginRegisterVC alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:YES];
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
UIView *registerPanel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
registerPanel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show me the code where you alloc and init the registerPanel. Is this a UIView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that parent view was UIImageView which by default have userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the

```
[registerBtnTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(submitRegister) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
[registerBtnTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(submitRegister:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The method signature is `submitRegister:` (not `submitRegister`).
You don't need to declare the method in the header.

If this doesn't help check the frame of the host view. When the button is outside of the frame it can be shown but it won't accept touches.

I don't understand what you are asking in your edit.

Comment: 1. `[registerBtnTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(submitRegister:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` is used if you want to pass the current button to `submitRegister`method - it's useful if I have multiple buttons which call one method; 2. I've tried it despite point one and it don't work. I will check the frame.

Comment: Did you check whether the button is in the frame of the registerPanel? Is the `userInteractionEnabled` property of all superviews set to YES?

Comment: In this case I don't use `userInteractionEnabled` in my classes